# Delete Specific Lines (Numbers) in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to delete specific line numbers.. like

```
7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 55, 56, 57, 58, 63, 68, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 83, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 114, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 132, 133, 135, 136, 138, 139, 145, 160, 165, 166, 167, 170, 171, 176, 177, 178, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 198, 199, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 214, 215, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 241, 245, 247, 248, 249, 258, 259, 260, 261, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 286, 294, 295, 297, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 340, 342, 343, 344
```

is this possible in notepad++ ?

Comment: Is there anyway you can define the criteria that determines a line is deleted? I don't think Notepad++ macros are powerful enough for this so perhaps a batch script solution is better.. if you provide details maybe we can have a crack at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your need for flexibility, you could use a macro and record your actions, using the down arrow x number of times corresponding to the line number. Then hit shift+'end' and delete.

This will not work if the line numbers are variable. Please clarify.

EDIT:

I don't think Notepad++ is powerful enough to do something like that, but you could easily do it in PHP or some other language.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
$lines = array(1,2,3,5,6,8,etc.)

get($file)

foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
  if(!array_key_exists($key,$lines))
    $new_file[] = $line
}

foreach($new_file as $line)
  write($file,$line."\n");
```

Just to reiterate, this is pseudo code. If you'd like code PHP, Java, or Perl, I can provide that for you.

Comment: Hi james, the line numbers are variables. I am basically trying to strip off some unused styles off a css file.